# Manter sempre uma section visível em php

Tags: javascript, html

Criei um menu e para cada um deles criei uma `section`. Depois do menu criei um `form` com os `inputs` para filtrar por colaborar e por data. Depois criei as `sections`.

Código:

```js
<script>
$(function() {
  $(".btn-show").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    el = $(this).data('element');
    $(el).show();
    $("section > div").not(el).hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="vertical">
        <ul class="men clearfix1">
        <li><a href="#Tarefas Semanais">Tarefas Semanais</a>
                <ul class="sub-men clearfix1">
                    <li><a href="#s1" class="btn-show" data-element="#minhaDiv">Gerais Quartos Ala A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#s2" class="btn-show" data-element="#minhaDiv1">Gerais Quartos Ala B</a>
                 </ul>
       </li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
</div>

<div class="modal-body" style="float: left; margin-top: 10em;">
 <form action="" method="post">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
   <div class="form-group">
     <h6><label for="Colaborador-text" class="col-form-label">Colaborador</label></h6>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      <h6><select style="width:150px" name="pesquisar_colaborador">
  <option></option>
  <option value="teste">teste</option>
    <option value="teste1">teste1</option>
   </select></h6>
   </div>
  </div>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
   <div class="form-group">
      <h6><label for="Inicio-name" class="col-form-label">Inicio</label></h6>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      <h6><input type="Date" id="inicio" name="inicio" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>"></h6>
   </div>
  </div>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
   <div class="form-group">
      <h6><label for="Fim-name" class="col-form-label">Fim</label></h6>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      <h6><input type="Date" id="fim" name="fim" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>"></h6>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Consultar</button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>

<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
if(isset($_POST['pesquisar_colaborador']) && isset($_POST['inicio']) && isset($_POST['fim'])){
 $pesquisar1 = $_POST['pesquisar_colaborador'];
 $inicio = $_POST['inicio'];
 $fim = $_POST['fim'];
?>

<section id="s1">
<div class="wrapper" id="minhaDiv" style="display:none" >
<?php 

$result_cursos = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.RegistolimpALAA WHERE Colaborador LIKE '%$pesquisar1%' AND `data` BETWEEN '$inicio' AND '$fim' ORDER BY dataregisto DESC";
$resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos);
$tabela .= '<div class="teste" id="tabela41" style="float: center" table align="center"><form  class="form-validate" action="" method="post"> 
 <div class="campo">
         
            <h1>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Consulta Tarefas Semanais Limpeza</strong>
            </center>
        </h1><br>
   
    </div> 
</form> ';
 
$tabela .= '<table border="5"><h4>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Móveis Arrastados e Rodapés dos Roupeiros (3ª feira) ALA A</strong>
            </center>
        </h4><br>';

$tabela .= '<tr>';

$tabela .='<thead>';

$tabela .= '<tr>';

$tabela .= '<th style="font-size: 12px;">Data Registo</th>';

$tabela .= '<th style="font-size: 12px;">Data da Tarefa</th>';

$tabela .= '<th style="font-size: 12px;">Colaborador</th>';

$tabela .= '<th style="font-size: 12px;">Observação</th>';

$tabela .= '</tr>';

$tabela .='</thead>'; 

$tabela .='<tbody>';

while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {
 
$tabela .= '<tr>';

$tabela .= '<td style="width:30px; font-size: 12px;">'.$rows_cursos['dataregisto'].'</td>';

$tabela .= '<td style="width:30px; font-size: 12px;">'.$rows_cursos['data'].'</td>';

$tabela .= '<td style="width:200px; font-size: 12px;">'.$rows_cursos['Colaborador'].'</td>';

$tabela .= '<td style="width:200px; font-size: 12px;">'.$rows_cursos['Observacao'].'</td>';

$tabela .= '</tr>'; 

}
$tabela .= '</tr>';

$tabela .='</tbody>'; 

$tabela .= '</table>';

$tabela .= '</div>';

echo $tabela;

?> 
</div>
</section>

<section id="s2">
<div class="wrapper" id="minhaDiv1" style="display:none">
<?php 

$result_cursos1 = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.RegistolimpALAB WHERE Colaborador1 LIKE '%$pesquisar1%' AND `data1` BETWEEN '$inicio' AND '$fim' ORDER BY dataregisto1 DESC";
$resultado_cursos1 = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos1);
$tabela1 .= '<div class="teste" id="tabela42" style="float: center" table align="center"><form  class="form-validate" action="" method="post"> 
 <div class="campo">
         
            <h1>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Consulta Tarefas Semanais Limpeza</strong>
            </center>
        </h1><br>
   
    </div> 
</form> ';
$tabela1 .= '<table border="5"><h4>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Móveis Arrastados e Rodapés dos Roupeiros (5ª feira) ALA B</strong>
            </center>
        </h4>';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .='<thead>';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<th style="font-size: 12px;">Data Registo</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th style="font-size: 12px;">Data da Tarefa</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th style="font-size: 12px;">Colaborador</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th style="font-size: 12px;">Observação</th>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</thead>'; 

$tabela1 .='<tbody>';

while($rows_cursos1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos1)) {
 
$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<td style="width:30px; font-size: 12px;">'.$rows_cursos1['dataregisto1'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td style="width:30px; font-size: 12px;">'.$rows_cursos1['data1'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td style="width:200px; font-size: 12px;">'.$rows_cursos1['Colaborador1'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td style="width:200px; font-size: 12px;">'.$rows_cursos1['Observacao1'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>'; 

}
$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</tbody>'; 

$tabela1 .= '</table>';

$tabela1 .= '</div>';

echo $tabela1;

?> 
</div>
</section>

<?php
}
?>
```

Mostro na imagem o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como mostro na imagem não tenho nenhuma `section` visível. Para ficar visível tenho de clicar no menu do lado esquerdo. Então faço o filtro por exemplo pela data e clico no botão consultar. Para ver o resultado retornado tenho de clicar num dos submenus.

Pretendia que ao clicar no botão consultar a primeira `section` ficasse visível sem ter de clicar em nenhum dos submenus. Depois disso é que clicava no submenu que pretendia.

Answer (score 1):

Tente mudar a classe {.btn-toggle} do botão e colocar uma outra para testar. Provavelmente, esta classe é do bootstrap que está dando toogle no elemento.

No seu código JavaScript ( mais precisamente nessa parte $(el).toggle(); ) vc também esta escondendo e mostrando cada vez que clica no botão.

Comment: editei a pergunta para tentar simplificar a explicação do meu problema, poderá ver se me consegue ajudar?

Comment: Olha, tem formas melhores de fazer isso, mas acho que resolve seu problema se no evento click do botão você fizer o click do elemento manualmente, por exemplo: $("section").click();

Comment: Se não conseguir a noite eu te ajudo certinho.

Comment: estava a dizer assim: `$(document).ready(function () {
$('#teste').click(function(){  
           $("section").click(); 
      });
}); `

Comment: não consegui resolver, à noite se puder ajudar agradeço. Obrigado